# How make a compressed tar when there are too many filenames for the shell to expand on a single line?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, find, tar

Normally I would just do something like:

```
tar -czf archive.tar.gz *.csv
```

But when there are too many files in the directory for the shell to expand on a single line this doesn't work.

In these cases I would normally resort to using `find`. Something like:

```
find /path -name '*.csv' -exec tar -rf "./archive.tar.gz" {} +;`
```

But this only seems to work if I don't include the `-z` option because you can't append to compressed archives, and using `-c` instead of `-r` will overwrite the first archive since find runs tar multiple times.

The only other solution I could come up with is to create a .tar file with `find` (as above) and then use a second command to compress it. Is there a better way to handle cases like this?

I'm using Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: You can create a tar archive and compress it later. (As used to be the way we did things back when we walked uphill to school, both ways).

Comment: Your find command suffers from the same problem with too many arguments since the glob is expanded before find sees it. You should use `find -name '*.csv'` instead.

Comment: Indeed, I fixed it now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As a robust solution, use `find` to separate filenames by a null character, and then pipe directly to `tar`, which [reads null-delimited input](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#SEC107):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.csv' -print0 |
tar -czf archive.tgz --null -T -
```

This will now handle *all* file names correctly and is not limited by the number of files either.

<sub>Using `ls` to generate a list of filenames to be parsed by another program [is a common antipattern](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) that should be avoided whenever possible. `find` can generate null-delimited output (`-print0`) that most utilities can read or parse further. Since the null character is the only character that cannot appear in a filename (and the `/`, obviously), you'll always be safe with that.</sub>

Answer (score 10):

No, you cannot [append to a compressed tar file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13093/add-update-a-file-to-an-existing-tar-gz-archive) without uncompressing it first.

However, tar can [accept its list of files to process from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033857/tar-archiving-that-takes-input-from-a-list-of-files), so you can just do:

```
ls *.csv > temp.txt
tar -zcf ball.tgz -T temp.txt
```

@slhck points out that the above solution will not work if there are spaces (and probably other annoying characters) in your filenames.  This version encloses each filename in double quotes:

```
ls *.csv | sed -e 's/^\(.*\)$/"\1"/' > temp.txt
tar -zcf ball.tgz -T temp.txt
```

(This will of course break if you have double quotes in your filenames, in which case you get what you deserve. :)

Comment: If you want to do it in a single command you could use `tar -zcf ball.tgz -T <( ls *.csv)` or `tar -zcf ball.tgz -T <( find -name '*.csv')`.  See http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html#PROCESS-SUB

Comment: That's not quite the solution I was thinking of. See my answer for a solution that doesn't choke on file names. Don't blame users for creating files with spaces or double quotes in the path – all Linux tools can handle this correctly, you just need to apply the proper options. In general, as a good tip, once you find yourself using `ls` to enumerate files other than just *looking* at them, something will probably break.